# How to properly Capture JavaScript Click event to Hide and Show a Div?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, ecmascript-6

I have 1 input area and one popup area when I click to input, the popup will show, and when I click anywhere else in the body (except popup and input), I want the popup to go hidden.

```js
function show(){
    document.getElementById('content').style.display = 'flex'
  }
```

```css
*{margin: 0;padding: 0;}
  .main{width: 100%;height: 100%;background: rgb(160, 160, 160);}
  input {width: 400px;height: 60px;}
  .input, #content {display: flex;justify-content: center;padding-top: 20px;}
  #content {display:none}
  button {width: 150px;height: 50px;margin-top: 20px;}
  h2 {background: #000;color: aliceblue;margin-top: 20px;text-align: center;}
  .content-inner {width:400px;height: 200px;background: rgb(109, 68, 68);;}
```

```html
<!-- Main -->
<div class="main">

  <!-- input -->
  <div class="input">
    <input type="text" onfocus="show()">
  </div>

  <!-- Popup -->
  <div id="content">
    <div class="content-inner" align="center">
      <button>Demo Button</button>
      <div>
        <h2>Demo Heading</h2>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

</div>
```

Comment: There's also the `blur` event (triggered when an element loses focus). See how you can listen to it with [pure JavaScript](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/blur_event) and [jQuery](https://api.jquery.com/blur).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I detect a click outside an element?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/152975/how-do-i-detect-a-click-outside-an-element)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can listen to document `click` events and then check if the click happened in the `input` area or somewhere else, then show or hide the modal.

Since your whole visible `div` in the first place is a `div` with `class="input"` and you got an input inside it, so whenever the `click` event does not contain input class it should hide the modal and vise versa.

```js
const content = document.getElementById('content');

document.addEventListener("click", function(event) {
  if (!event.target.classList.contains("input")) {
    content.style.display = 'flex';
  } else {
    content.style.display = 'none';
  }
})
```

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.main {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background: rgb(160, 160, 160);
}

input {
  width: 400px;
  height: 60px;
}

.input,
#content {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  padding-top: 20px;
}

#content {
  display: none
}

button {
  width: 150px;
  height: 50px;
  margin-top: 20px;
}

h2 {
  background: #000;
  color: aliceblue;
  margin-top: 20px;
  text-align: center;
}

.content-inner {
  width: 400px;
  height: 200px;
  background: rgb(109, 68, 68);
  ;
}
```

```html
<!-- Main -->
<div class="main">

  <!-- input -->
  <div class="input">
    <input type="text">
  </div>

  <!-- Popup -->
  <div id="content">
    <div class="content-inner" align="center">
      <button>Demo Button</button>
      <div>
        <h2>Demo Heading</h2>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

</div>
```

---

Also if in any case, you want to close the modal if the `click` event happened anywhere outside the modal itself or `input` area you can check for another condition to see whether `click` event happened inside `div` with `id="content"` or not.

So the final code should be something like this:

```js
const content = document.getElementById('content');

document.addEventListener("click", function(event) {
  if (!event.target.classList.contains("input") && event.target.id !== "content") {
    content.style.display = 'flex';
  } else {
    content.style.display = 'none';
  }
})
```

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.main {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background: rgb(160, 160, 160);
}

input {
  width: 400px;
  height: 60px;
}

.input,
#content {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  padding-top: 20px;
}

#content {
  display: none
}

button {
  width: 150px;
  height: 50px;
  margin-top: 20px;
}

h2 {
  background: #000;
  color: aliceblue;
  margin-top: 20px;
  text-align: center;
}

.content-inner {
  width: 400px;
  height: 200px;
  background: rgb(109, 68, 68);
  ;
}
```

```html
<!-- Main -->
<div class="main">

  <!-- input -->
  <div class="input">
    <input type="text">
  </div>

  <!-- Popup -->
  <div id="content">
    <div class="content-inner" align="center">
      <button>Demo Button</button>
      <div>
        <h2>Demo Heading</h2>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

</div>
```

---

So if you want to add another listener to the content inside the modal you can just define another event listener for it just like this:

```js
const content = document.getElementById("content");
const button = document.querySelector("button");
const contentInner = document.querySelector(".content-inner");

document.addEventListener("click", function(event) {
  if (!event.target.classList.contains("input") && event.target.id !== "content") {
    content.style.display = 'flex';
  } else {
    content.style.display = 'none';
  }
})

button.addEventListener("click", function() {
  const span = document.createElement("span");
  const text = document.createTextNode("newer span");
  span.append(text);
  contentInner.append(span)
})
```

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.main {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background: rgb(160, 160, 160);
}

input {
  width: 400px;
  height: 60px;
}

.input,
#content {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  padding-top: 20px;
}

#content {
  display: none
}

button {
  width: 150px;
  height: 50px;
  margin-top: 20px;
}

h2 {
  background: #000;
  color: aliceblue;
  margin-top: 20px;
  text-align: center;
}

.content-inner {
  width: 400px;
  height: 200px;
  background: rgb(109, 68, 68);
  ;
}
```

```html
<!-- Main -->
<div class="main">

  <!-- input -->
  <div class="input">
    <input type="text">
  </div>

  <!-- Popup -->
  <div id="content">
    <div class="content-inner" align="center">
      <button>Demo Button</button>
      <div>
        <h2>Demo Heading</h2>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use **jQuery mouseup** event (.mouseup()) with target property (event.target) to detect click the event and hide div when clicking outside of the specific element.

```
<script>
$(document).mouseup(function(e){
    var container = $("#elementID");

    // If the target of the click isn't the container
    if(!container.is(e.target) && container.has(e.target).length === 0){
        container.hide();
    }
});
</script>
```